# Need Batch File/Script To Find Multiple Usernames Using Their Machine Names

Tags: batch, script, username

I have a list of about 200 machine names. I need to get the UserName of the person on each of those machines.

I can do it individually using the following command. But I'm not looking to do this 200 times and then manually write the results in spreadsheet.

```
wmic.exe /node:"<MachineName>" ComputerSystem Get UserName
```

I've been searching for a script that will run through a list of about 200 machine names one by one, and document the result back into a spreadsheet or text document. The format isn't as important as just being able to get that info out of the CMD line and email a document to someone.

Comment: *get the UserName of the person on each of those machines*... do you mean the username of the *currently logged on* user?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a script writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put all the computers in a text file called `comps.lst` this should work:

`for /f %a in (comps.lst) do @wmic.exe /node:"%a" ComputerSystem Get UserName`

Comment: `<MachineName>` or `%a`?

Comment: It would work if I could substitute <MachineName> in the script with the text entry (the actual machine name) on each line.

Comment: Sorry.  Fixed to replace with %a